# Get list of all databases from server

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to create functionality mentioned in the title. The idea that I have in mind is that I have a form, where I can select the server/-s (i have achieved that with a simple dialog list). So far I have this in my dialog list:

```
servers:=@Name([Abbreviate];@DbColumn("";   @If(@Subset(@DbName;1)="";"";@Subset(@DbName;1)) :"names.nsf";"($Servers)";1));
@Unique(@If(@IsError(servers);"";servers))
```

What I'm having problem is with selecting the databases available in the selected server/-s. Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this? Haven't really tried anything because I couldn't find the information.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for: Doing a @DBColumn for all Server- documents in the names.nsf does not have anything  to do with the title of your question... Please clarify!

Comment: @TorstenLink the idea is that I can select a server (I have achieved that with code above). When I select a server I get list of available databases. When I get the database, I get list of the documents in the database. What I'm having trouble is the second step, after I select the server, how can I get the list of databases in the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your needs, it does not have to be that complicated: [@Prompt](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PROMPT.html) has a special mode for picking a database:

```
result := @Prompt([ChooseDatabase];"";"");
FIELD Server := result[1];
FIELD Filename := result[2];
FIELD Title := result[3]
```